# Hadoop HIVE - How to query part of rows

Tags: hive

If i have below table;

```
table name : mytable
columns : id, name, sex, age, score
row1 : 1,Albert,M,30,70
row2 : 2,Scott,M,34,60
row3 : 3,Amilie,F,29,75
...
row100 : 100,Jim,M,35,80
```

I want to select them five times.

```
1st iteration : row1 ~ row20
2nd iteration : row21 ~ row40
...
5th iteration : row81 ~ row100
```

How can I query Hive? Is there any known query?
Below returns all 100 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

But I really want to see only 20 rows each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can easily do this by Limit Offset in `Myqsl`. Hive support limit but not Offset(not 100% sure)
But you can limit your output by

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
LIMIT 20;
```

it will give only 20 records, but not 20-40;

You can do by `ROW_NUMBER` in hive

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER over (Order by id)  as rowid FROM mytable
where rowid > 0 and rowid <=20;
```

next time you have to change the condition in where clause.

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER over (Order by id)  as rowid FROM mytable
    where rowid > 20 and rowid <=40;
```

You can also pass the rowid variable using text file or set the variable;[run os command and set out put to hive variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413558/run-os-command-and-set-out-put-to-hive-variable)

Answer (score 7):

Update on this one. Just in case someone else tries this solution now.

For me it only worked with a brackets after the row number and a new SELECT statement around the query with the where clause as the alias 'rowid' wasn't available in the inner SELECT. Took me a while to figure it out.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by id) as rowid FROM mytable
) t1
WHERE rowid > 0 and rowid <= 20;
```

Answer (score -1):

**offset feature is supported in Hive 2.0. or higher version.**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT [offset,] row_count;
```

You can query for the mentioned requirement is as follows.

1. SELECT * FROM mytable order by id LIMIT 0,20
2. SELECT * FROM mytable order by id LIMIT 20,20
3. SELECT * FROM mytable order by id LIMIT 40,20
4. SELECT * FROM mytable order by id LIMIT 60,20
5. SELECT * FROM mytable order by id LIMIT 80,20 // returns the  81th to the 100th records

Comment: i think this command only works on several version