# run os command and set out put to hive variable

Tags: hive, hiveql

Is it possible to run something like this in **Hive CLI**?

I am trying to pass file contents as a variable to another query.

```
set column_list=!cat /home/user/filename.lst ;
create table tabname as select $column_list from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a query file you pass the variables as hiveconf
hive -hiveconf var1=abcd -f file.txt

or you can construct your query and then pass it to hive cli using -e
hive -e "create table ..."

Answer (score 0):

file filename.lst

```
line
```

make a file test.sh,

```
temp=$(cat /home/user/filename.lst)

hive -f test.hql -hiveconf var=$temp
```

make a another file test.hql

```
create table test(${hiveconf:var} string);
```

on terminal

```
sh -x test.sh
```

It will pass the line to the test.hql and it will create a table with line as column;

note- all files should be in same directory .This script is passing only one variable.